# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

When you reduce the browser window a separate layout has been put for iPhone screens;
you can see two arrows and when you click the right arrow it will move to the next slider, but I am not able to see the cubes.
When I looked in close I see one error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/UL3R2/

```
 var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
            callback: function(e, pos) {

                var i = bullets.length;
                while (i--) {
                    bullets[i].className = ' ';
                }
                bullets[pos].className = 'on';
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

            }
        }),
```

Comment: You need to debug this. `console.log(pos);` What is being returned?

Comment: i tried it shows this how to fix it ReferenceError: pos is not defined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "pos is not defined"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error

Comment: pos returns this '<li data-index="1" style="display: table-cell; width: 417px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid red; left: -417px; transition-duration: 300ms; transform: translateX(0px);">' and  bullets[i] returns '<em class=" "> <em class=" "> <em class=" ">' so obviously bullets[pos] is undefined.